# OutOfMemoryException in Custom Serialization - JSON.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization, json.net, datacontractjsonserializer

I created my own Custom Serialization method with JSON.NET, 
the method looks like :

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var Obj = (xObject)value;
    writer.WriteStartArray();

    foreach(var TargetObject in Obj)                        
    {
       writer.WriteStartObject();
       writer.WritePropertyName(TargetObject.Data.Key);
       writer.WriteValue(TargetObject.Data.Value);
       writer.WriteEndObject();         
    } 
    writer.WriteEndArray();        
}
```

I got an `OutOfMemoryException` exception at `writer.WriteValue(TargetObject.Data.Value)`, saying insufficient memory, any idea that I can keep my custom serialization but avoid this issue?

Note, yes, you are right,the object I'm trying to serialize is more than 1GB.

Comment: Are you writing to memory?  Write directly to disk.

Comment: It might just be a typo in the question, but the call to `writer.WriteEndArray();` needs to be moved outside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @kristianp, I'm sending the data back as http request...

Comment: @dbc, not typo, this code works with small mount of data, but not any data that like 1GB, so its certain sth to do with the "writer" memroy usage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found finally, the reason is because the exception from overflowing the String type from .NET. So , simply, its just too big data for a String field, there is no solution as there isn't a problem with json.net, my solution is to simplifying my data, or output as a file on drive rather than storing its whole data any time in memory as string field, just impossible....

Answer (score 0):

Try using streaming and PushStreamContent as per [this blog.](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/)

You may have to abandon the JsonWriter and do more manual serialisation using an unbuffered stream.

Comment: not quite, what i found is the internal exception overflow on String Type...its just too big, the built in String cant handle...